# Rules of style for Spanish

Tags: gramática, puntuación

I know that there are several sources in English to check for commonly-accepted rules of style. This is, regarding how punctuation should look in non-common cases (eg., if the period should be used or not in the abbreviation on this parenthesis because it looks awful next to the colon).

So, I was wondering: is there anything like this for the Spanish language?

Answer (score 4):

The ["Libro de Estilo de El País"](http://estudiantes.elpais.com/libroestilo/indice_estilos.htm) is a classic.

Comment: It took me a while to write this comment because I actually read it all before commenting. I think it does not fulfill my expectations, although it gets close. It does cover usage of proper grammatics (only for journalism) and it does cover common error and usage of symbols. However, that is a minor element in the rest of the context, and I think that is the main point I want to see extended and with full detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [fundéu](http://www.fundeu.es/). It's very usefull because this site highlights the "trending topics" in the news.